# How to validate the focus of the WebDriver while switching frames

Tags: selenium, selenium-webdriver, iframe, webdriver, frame

I go to the frame on the site using the code

```
driver.SwithToFrame(0)
```

How can I find out now in focus the main site or frame?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To validate if the focus is on the *Top Browsing Context* or within the [iframe](/questions/tagged/iframe), you can switch to the **`active_element`** and then print the `outerHTML` and you can use the following solution:

```
driver.switch_to.frame(0)
element = driver.switch_to.active_element
print(element.get_attribute("outerHTML"))
```